# How to make a local template for a linux container and point to that

Tags: debian, lxc

The thing is let's say I want to make my linux container. The first command invariably is :-

```
sudo lxc-create -t debian -n p1
```

It's usually 'ubuntu' for the template name but as I am a Debian fanboy have replaced it with debian. The end result of either is the same, it starts downloading the components from debian.org via the lxc-debian template written at /usr/share/lxc/templates.

```
$ sudo lxc-create -t debian -n debian-n
[sudo] password for shirish: 
debootstrap is /usr/sbin/debootstrap
Checking cache download in /var/cache/lxc/debian/rootfs-wheezy-amd64 ... 
Downloading debian minimal ...
I: Retrieving Release
```

I do have a local debian-wheezy.iso image file. Is there a way to tell it to instead use that local .iso image instead of going to the web.

Answer (score 12):

the argument supplied to `-t` is a file in `/usr/share/lxc/templates`. Looking at the `lxc-debian` template, the routine that does the downloading is called `download_debian()`, and the work is performed by `debootstrap`:

```
    debootstrap --verbose --variant=minbase --arch=$arch \
    --include=$packages \
    "$release" "$cache/partial-$release-$arch" $MIRROR
```

Looking at the manpage, `debootstrap` can use a local directory for the mirror files rather than a network address

```
…MIRROR can be an http:// or https:// URL, a file:/// URL,
or an ssh:/// URL.
```

So, to use your local data, mount your ISO onto the filesystem somewhere; define the MIRROR environment variable; invoke `lxc-create`.

The signed release file didn't appear to be in the ISO I tried, so I had to also pass `--no-check-gpg` to `debootstrap`, which meant editing the template file in `/usr/share/lxc/templates` to add the argument:

```
--- lxc-debian~ 2015-03-04 10:04:12.628619962 +0000
+++ lxc-debian  2015-03-04 10:04:17.420619851 +0000
@@ -232,7 +232,6 @@
     # download a mini debian into a cache
     echo "Downloading debian minimal ..."
     debootstrap --verbose --variant=minbase --arch=$arch \
+   --no-check-gpg \
         --include=$packages \
         "$release" "$cache/partial-$release-$arch" $MIRROR
     if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
```

So, once adjusted:

```
# mount -o loop debian-7.8.0-amd64-CD-1.iso /mnt
# export MIRROR=file:///mnt
# lxc-create -t debian -n p1 -- -r wheezy
```

worked.