# how to tell lxc to not use /usr/share/lxc/templates for making a linux container

Tags: debian, lxc

This is a follow-up question to [How to make a local template for a linux container and point to that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186638/how-to-make-a-local-template-for-a-linux-container-and-point-to-that)

Now, in that it seems that a user has to make some changes to `/usr/share/lxc/templates` in order to make the container (just couple of words though but still). What if, I as a user do not want lxc to use the templates therein but use a template I have made in /home only ? Is there anyway ?